# what method i must use instead of DeviceListAdapter in android studio

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to scan unpaired devices through Bluetooth. Devices are not shown in the list. is there a problem of not using DeviceListAdapter ?? if it is then which option i have to use to show devices because in android studio there is no option of DeviceListAdapter.

This is button code :

```
btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {
        if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            IntentFilter discoverDeviceIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice
                    .ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, discoverDeviceIntent);
        }
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            IntentFilter discoverDeviceIntent = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, discoverDeviceIntent);

        }
    }
});

//and here is broadcast_receiver code to receive device

broadcastReceiver =new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        unpaired_list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            unpaired_list.add(device);

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Showing Unpaired Device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            final ArrayAdapter upadapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            unpairlv.setAdapter(upadapter);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: where are you adding unpaired_list to the upadapter?

Comment: where i have to add ? should i have to pass 3rd argument of ArrayAdapter ??

Comment: its fine ... sometime we have to work 1 or 2 days to find a little mistake ... thanks you noticed ... but now it is showing one device at a time ... not all devices in a list ...

Comment: Please find the updated answer to solve this issue and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try  adding as below

```
upadapter.addAll(unpaired_list);
```

add it just after creating upadapter in the below line.

```
final ArrayAdapter upadapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

Edited Answer

Declare global variables

```
ArrayAdapter upadapter;
ArrayList unpaired_list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Add this in oncreate()

```
upadapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
```

change the broadcastReceiver onReceive method.

```
broadcastReceiver =new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            unpaired_list.add(device);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Showing Unpaired Device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            upadapter.add(device);
            unpairlv.setAdapter(upadapter);
        }
    }
};
```